# where should I dispatch my redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-props

I am learning react and redux, and I just have a small question about where should I dispatch and share my redux store to react components, should I share and dispatch my store in whatever components that need the store or I should share and dispatch my store in one main component and share that values as props to order components? 
  for example I have these three components and I have my states stored in one FlashCard component and share that states to Cardlist component using props and then the CardList component will send that props to Card component. is it the right thing to do? and also in card component I use dispatch because it seem more convenient, but should I use dispatch in my main component FlashCard as well and pass the change to Card component? thanks for your help.

```
import React from 'react';
import CardList from './cardList';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

const FlashCard =(props)=>{
    return (
    <div>
        <CardList
            cards={props.cards}
        />
    </div>
)}

const mapStateToProps=(state)=>({
    cards:state.cards
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,null)(FlashCard)
```

and

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from './card';

const CardList =(props)=>{
    const card=props.cards.map((c,i)=>(
        <Card
            key={i}
            card={c}
        />
    ))
    return(
    <div>{card}</div>
)}

export default CardList
```

and a Card component to render all the cards

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { showCardInfo, hideCardInfo } from '../redux/flashCardRedux';

const Card =(props)=>{
    const onCardClick=()=>{
        console.log(props.card.id)
    }
    return (
    <div>

        {props.card.showInfo?

        <div
            onClick={()=>props.dispatch(hideCardInfo(props.card.id))}
        >{props.card.name}</div>
        :
        <div
            className='card'
            onClick={()=>props.dispatch(showCardInfo(props.card.id))}
        >
            <div className='img'>
                <img src={props.card.img}/>
                <h3>{props.card.name}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>}

    </div>

)}

export default connect()(Card)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, I have found it best practice to only refer to `dispatch` in the main component and only pass in what the child components require as properties. This not only means that you are not passing `dispatch` around to everything, but also allows for unit testing of the smaller components if required.

It also keeps the smaller components much "lighter" in that they only have what they need, and can easily then be rendered in other areas of your app.

In the future, if you ever wanted to swap out Redux for something similar, it means you are then only having to edit code in the main component rather than everywhere in your system.

Answer (score 1):

```
Its always recommended to use dispatch in parent component because 
child is also part of parent but as per requirement you can shift.

as you have parent to child connection either you can connect in 
parent and pass data as `props` or either you can take out in child 
component itself, it depend upon how complex your parent and 
child.however for smaller component always use as props else go for 
component wise connect.

for more info [follow this](https://reactjs.org/)
```